# Proverbs 16:33, why the but? and outcome vs justice

Tags: proverbs, predestination

Most translations say something like,

> People cast lots, BUT God determines all outcomes.

What is the justification of the Contrajunction BUT?

And why is 'outcomes' related to the lots, as opposed to outcomes in general? say justice?

For example:

> People cast lots. Yet God (brings) all justice.

Comment: *What is the justification of the contrajunction **but** ?* - Probably because the Septuagint has *para*.

Answer (score 1):

> People cast lots, BUT God determines all outcomes.

Your paraphrase omits one important detail:

> The lot is cast **into the lap**,
>       but its every decision is from the Lord. (NIV)

The verse means to say that the lot is cast *in secret*. Compare the sword which Ehud hid on his right thigh (Judges 3:16). The point is that even though the lot is cast in secret, in the lap, where no one can see it, the Lord determines its outcome.

However, the Hebrew word for "but" isn't distinguished from "and" in this case, and the rendering of "but" is more interpretation than translation. Hebrew doesn't require "but" when contrasting two things, but English does. (Try replacing "but English does" with "and English does" in the previous sentence, and you'll see why.)

---

> And why is 'outcomes' related to the lots, as opposed to outcomes in general? say justice?

Once again, a minor detail is missing from the paraphrase:

> The lot is cast into the lap,
>       but **its** every decision is from the Lord. (NIV)

The outcome *of the lots* is related to the lots. The verse doesn't say that every outcome in the world is related to the lots. It could also have said as generally as possible, "People do a lot of things, but the Lord determines everything." But that is simply not what the verse says. The verse is just giving one example of what the Lord determines, and leaves to the readers to figure out the rest for themselves.